# Is the init section functions called first or the constructor functions?

Tags: c++, gcc, initializer

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

void preinit_void();
void init_void();

__attribute__((section(".init_array")))
    void (*p_init)(void) = &init_void;

void constructor_void() __attribute__((constructor));
void constructor_void() {
    printf(__FUNCTION__);
}

__attribute__((section(".preinit_array")))
    void (*p_preinit)(void) = &preinit_void;


void preinit_void() {
    printf(__FUNCTION__);
}

void init_void() {
    printf(__FUNCTION__);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}
```

On running the code the output is

```
preinit_voidinit_voidconstructor_voidmain
```

If I were to change the code to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

void preinit_void();
void init_void();

void constructor_void() __attribute__((constructor));
void constructor_void() {
    printf(__FUNCTION__);
}

__attribute__((section(".init_array")))
    void (*p_init)(void) = &init_void;

__attribute__((section(".preinit_array")))
    void (*p_preinit)(void) = &preinit_void;


void preinit_void() {
    printf(__FUNCTION__);
}

void init_void() {
    printf(__FUNCTION__);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}
```

The output changes to:

```
preinit_voidconstructor_voidinit_voidmain
```

I am confused as to which section is initialized first. Does the output change merely due to parsing by compiler (that it found `.init_array` section first instead of the `constructor`) or is there a proper initialization sequence for it?

Comment: The order is undefined, don't rely on it.

Comment: I see. What functionality do they provide?

Comment: For [`__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((destructor))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html), you can specify a priority. In any case, try to avoid using any of these (non-standard attributes, ELF-specific sections, etc.) if you can; to make programs more portable (across non-ELF loaders/OSs and compilers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On current (GNU) systems, references to ELF constructor functions are placed into the `.init_array` section, just like the entries you add manually.  This why the executing order changed when you changed the source code order.  GCC and binutils have a language extension for using separate sections based on priority, and the link editor will serialize everything into a final `.init_array` section for each application/shared object (based on source code and link order, after sorting by priority).

The constructor arrays for different shared objects are executed after performing a topological sort based on the dependencies between objects (as expressed through the `DT_NEEDED` tag), so that objects are initialized after their dependencies.

This goes way beyond what is required by C++ for initialization, but it is more or less specified in various (GNU) ABI-related documents, and it is not going to change.  Some aspects might change due to the introduction of new features (e.g., multiple `DF_1_INITFIRST` objects, although this one is a bit baffling), but they will hopefully only affect processes which actually use those features.